# Having issues with RAM usage wordpress website

Tags: php, apache

Trying to figure this one out for quite some time now, I can't accept that my Wordpress is peaking my server limits with regular use, I think there is something wonky going on here. Could use some assistance pinpointing it!

For one, when looking at a snapshot of the usage I see this alot..

```
PID CMD TID CPU MEM IO  IOPS
151698  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  95      
151699  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  95      
151700  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  95      
151703  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  95      
151709  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  95      
151715  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  95      
151758  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  97      
151760  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  97      
156720  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  111     
156726  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  111     
156731  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  111     
156737  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  111     
156738  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  111     
156740  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  111     
156743  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  111     
156757  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  117     
156761  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  117     
156762  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  117     
156763  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  117     
156777  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  117     
156780  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  97      
156785  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  97      
156786  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  97      
156792  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  97      
156798  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  97      
281957  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
281975  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
281978  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
281980  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
282026  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
282027  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
282032  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
282041  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
282050  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
282059  /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      0%  79      
310847  /usr/bin/php        0%  30      
310864  /usr/bin/php        0%  30      
311101  /usr/bin/php        0%  24      
311118  /usr/bin/php        0%  24      
311158  /usr/bin/php        0%  23      
311171  /usr/bin/php        0%  22      
311223  /usr/bin/php        1%  23      
311244  /usr/bin/php        0%  22      
312142  /usr/bin/php        0%  19      
312154  /usr/bin/php        0%  19      
312214  /usr/bin/php        0%  18      
312224  /usr/bin/php        1%  18      
312263  /usr/bin/php        1%  16      
312277  /usr/bin/php        0%  16      
312352  /usr/bin/php        1%  16      
312375  /usr/bin/php        0%  16      
312440  /usr/bin/php        1%  15      
312451  /usr/bin/php        0%  15      
312474  /usr/bin/php        0%  13      
312481  /usr/bin/php        0%  13      
312950  /usr/bin/php        0%  13      
313298  /usr/bin/php        0%  13      
313331  /usr/bin/php        1%  10      
313344  /usr/bin/php        1%  10      
313377  /usr/bin/php        1%  10      
313396  /usr/bin/php        0%  10      
313427  /usr/bin/php        0%  8       
313448  /usr/bin/php        0%  8       
313491  /usr/bin/php        1%  7       
313552  /usr/bin/php        1%  7       
313601  /usr/bin/php        1%  7       
313611  /usr/bin/php        1%  5
```

So, I want you guys to see my stats also here... [Cpanel Webstats Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iGmd.png)

I'm trying to work it out but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please check your query . its beacuse of your sql query is not optimized

Comment: Well, we hardly can tell you what takes so much CPU power when processing your requests. Maybe picture conversions?

Comment: @KakulSarma That would mean that the database server process has high load, not the http server or php.

Comment: your ram is fully utlized . thats way its impact with CPU also . If the query processing take time its happends . increse your RAM if you don't wish to optimaize

Comment: What should I optimize? When I was speaking to godaddy on the phone the girl said I had a high volume of database request.. I blew it off because I was thinking if it was the database it wouldn't do that to the RAM however she said something interesting -- That there were a large amount of requests from something like 'Wpseo seo cache validate" I will try optimizing my site more... I've been trying to , but if you look at the image it spikes every hour or so -- is there any way I could give you guys more information to help you help me? lol

Comment: When Your database has too many request and query is not optimized . the query procress goes in pending state and it consume more RAM and also impact CPU .

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you to reduce the CPU utilization

If your site receives a lot of traffic, it may lead to high CPU usage but in most cases there are other factors responsible for it. The following list describes some common software issues that can cause high CPU usage:

```
1)Inefficient scripts and excessive add ons/extensions/modules/plugins
2)Multiple WordPress websites
3)Frequent cron jobs or scheduled tasks
4)Hacked website
5)Comment spam
6)Uncontrolled search engine crawlers and automated robots activity
7)High volume of web traffic
7)Query not optimized
```

Details Here -
https://lunarpages.com/solutions-resolve-high-cpu-usage-websites/

Comment: This does not really answer the question, it should have been a comment maybe.